# Why is my Blazor date input type not working properly?

Tags: blazor

I am trying to create a page with a date picker, but I cannot get the Blazor to work properly. This is what I have going on:

**Page.razor:**

```
<div>
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input id="from" type="date" @bind="fromDate" />
</div>

@code {
    private DateTime fromDate;
}
```

However, when I run the project the date field reads `01/01/0001` and I cannot click into the box to edit the fields; I can, though, tab to the fields to edit them. When I click the calendar icon, it brings up the date picker starting at year `0001` and I am forced to scroll to 2021.

When I remove the `@bind="fromDate"` tag, the date picker widget works properly, but I, obviously, cannot retrieve the date for use.

I don't want to bind this to a model, I just want to grab the `DateTime` and manipulate it within my `@code{}` block.

---

**EDIT:**

I am also using Bootstrap 5.x, but that shouldn't really make a difference.

---

**EDIT #2:**

I removed the Bootstrap modifiers from that `input` and it still doesn't work, so Bootstrap is not the issue.

Comment: how about initializing  "fromDate" , something like    private DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Today;

Comment: Yes, that works for, at least, getting the starting date to the correct century. However, I still cannot click to edit the dates, I have to tab to the fields.

Comment: Have you tried with a different browser and checked your dev console for any js errors? Oh, and it shouldn't matter, but is this blazor client or server?

Comment: Sample works fine for me (with an initialized date because year 0001 isn't very helpful) with Edge and blazor WASM. What other css or framework are you using, or perhaps a browser extension?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with the build in component InputDate ? : 
<InputDate id="from" @bind-Value="fromDate" @bind-Value:format="dd/MM/yyyy" />

Comment: @Nikki9696 I have the same issue On Chrome and Edge; I cannot get the site to load at all on Firefox. This is a Blazor server side project. No JS errors.

Comment: @yasseros Yes ... same problem using `InputDate`.

Comment: @Brian.  I've tested both scenarios - with and without the bind in Blazor Server with Edge and Firefox.  The difference is that as your code is set up FromDate is the default date that is DateTime.MinValue, whereas the unbound input is null.  Once both have a value they respond the same.  To get the bind one to display dd/mm/yyyy you need to make  `fromDate` nullable `private DateTime? fromDate;` or `Nullable<DateTime> fromDate`.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I tried your suggestion, but it affects my code down further when I say: `fromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")`. On the `ToString()` it says "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument. Also, I still cannot click inside the date box to edit it.

Comment: that's weird , you have the same problem in a empty new project ?

Comment: @yasseros I have figured out the "not being able to click into the field" problem. See my "answer" below. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Brian.  On code further down, a null coalescing operator solves the problem - `string DisplayDate => fromDate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") ?? "No Date Selected";` or something similar depending on what you want the string to say.  I've never done much with nullable before Blazor, but much of the core Blazor code uses nullables so I've learnt!

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, this has nothing to do with Blazor, but is a "function" of HTML itself. This example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="GET" action="#">
                <input type="date" id="mydate" name="mydate" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Will do the same thing.

Apparently I **can** click into the date input field to edit it, it's just that there is no indicator of what element (e.g., day, month, year) I am currently editing.

If I click on `mm` I can enter a month, `dd` will let me enter a day, and `yyyy` will let me enter a year.

Like I said, however, there is nothing that indicates that I have successfully clicked within the field (like a highlight or change in background color, or whatnot) and what element of the date I am currently editing until I complete a date element, or tab to a new element.